# Keep getting error when pushing to git hub. Can somebody help me out

Tags: github

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/kokocat1313/Rusty'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: $ git push -u origin master -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/kokocat1313/Rusty
 + 4f15bd8...1bd9d4c master -> master (forced update)
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Comment: and thank you! your command `git push -u origin master -f` solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-f` as you did in the comments means you have overriden the remote history (commits) by your local history (the commits done locally in your master/main branch)

That happens especially with new GitHub repositories initialized with a `README` (instead of being completely empty), while you initialized a local repository locally on your workstation (instead of cloning it)

Note that you should be [using the branch `main`, not `master`](https://github.com/github/renaming).

```
git switch main
```

Comment: thank you so very much VonC. $ git push -u origin main
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'. github has no respond after having it pushed.

Comment: @JadeYu Yes, that is expected: you branch main is already at the same level than your previous master. You can now make new commits on it.